# Get loaded nibs to abide by IB constraints

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, interface-builder

I am having issues getting my "loaded xib" files to abide by the contraints placed on them in interface builder. When I use the preview to see what they look like, they look just as you would expect them to.

However, when running the program they appear "streched"

I added my table header as such:

```
let reserveHeaderFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, 164)
let reserveHeaderImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "ReserveHeader")!
let reserveHeaderView = UINib(nibName: "ReserveHeaderCell", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! ReserveHeaderCell
reserveHeaderView.ReserveHeaderImageView.image = reserveHeaderImage
reserveHeaderView.frame = reserveHeaderFrame
reserveHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
ReserveTableView.tableHeaderView = reserveHeaderView
```

For the table body cells, I used:

```
ReserveTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ReserveTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReserveTableViewCell")
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReserveTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReserveTableViewCell
```

This all works great, except the loaded nib files get stretched out.

I tried setting bounds, frames, no frame, translateautoresizingmask. Am I missing something here? Is this the "normal" behavior?

See attached SS:
[image: Screenshot]